# I have a gas leak on a 2011 F150 Ford truck

Tags: ford, leak, f-150

Gas seems to be leaking onto the top of the tank from the fuel line going to the engine. How can I find the source of the leak and repair it?

Comment: So what are we supposed to help you with excatly

Comment: 2011 Ford with a carburator?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please help us a little here with what you actually asking? As I see it, there really isn't a question here. We'd surely love to help you, but just need some more information from you as to your issue.

Comment: Some helpful information would be:    Is it leaking only when full or at all fuel levels?    Does it only leak when running (ignition on) or also when setting?   Can you see the tank top if you get under the truck?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I made some edits in hopes of clarifying your question. Please take a look and make sure I got it right.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you can see the area where the fuel seems to be leaking. If that's right you can start by inspecting the area and cleaning up any fuel that is sitting there. Be careful gasoline is **highly** flammable – don't have any ignition sources nearby as you're working. With the area cleared off you can do a few things to get started:

- If there is a hose clamp where the line connects to the tank check to see if it is loose.
- Inspect the fuel line for any signs of damage.
- Watch for new fuel to appear when the engine is running, if there is a fuel pump in the tank the line will be under pressure and may be leaking.
- In all likelihood your engine is fuel injected rather than carburated and there may be two fuel lines one delivering fuel to the engine and one returning unused fuel from the engine. Be sure to check both of them.
- If fuels isn't leaking at idle try driving the truck for a bit and then inspect again for leaked fuel.

As @spicetraders pointed suggested the leak may be dependent on the level of fuel in the tank or in the filler neck. So if you don't find fuel right away a good thing to do would be to fill the tank and check again. Fuel could also be leaking for the filler neck, the pump mounting flange, or the inlet and outlet fittings.

See if you can get a better idea of where the fuel is coming from and the conditions when it leaks (driving, at idle, full tank, etc.) and update your post with more details.

Comment: Note about recent fuel injected engines: they use a returnless fuel system where the pressure regulation is done via returning the excess fuel to the tank inside the pump which is situated inside the tank. Thus, don't be surprised if you find only one fuel line in a recent fuel injected engine.